# VLC Media Player stops streaming

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, vlc

I am trying to set up a security camera with a raspberry pi zero and raspberry pi camera, and I have gotten it to stream to VLC Media Player on my windows 10 laptop, but after about 1 minute of streaming, the stream will suddenly stop.  On a monitor directly connected to the raspberry pi, the video footage continues.  Does anyone know how to keep the VLC stream going?  Thank you!

Comment: share full logs and full code

Comment: I set Verbosity to 2 (debug) on VLC and here is what I got:
                                                                                                                                    
https://pastebin.com/1JWXj4kw